# Standard errors in weighted least squares

Tags: least-squares, weighted-regression

My data is a panel of countries by year.  Suppose my main RHS variable is a country's GDP and my main LHS variable classifies countries by whether the country is a democracy.

Is it desirably to weight each observation by the country's population in a particular year?  Since the world population has generally increased over time, does that put too much weight on more recent time periods?  To account for that, should I instead weight each country's population by say its population in the initial for each of that country's observations?

Also, isn't one purpose of weighting to correct for heteroskedasticity?  Should I still adjust standard errors by using robust standard errors?  Or, does using robust standard errors obviate the need to weight?

Should the weighted and unweighted regressions yield similar results?

Comment: The kind of weighting scheme which is desirable always depends on what you're trying to do. I think we need to know more about what kind of questions you're trying to answer before we can give any advice.

Comment: whuber: Is there a chat room for this forum?